About Combinatorial Interpretation
Doing some exercise, where one has to proof some identity by using combinatorial arguments,I noticed that it would be useful to get combinatorial "interpretations" for (typical) terms and symbols.
I saw alot of posts with analogies of choosing balls,paintings balls and similar things.
But I think a more formal approach would be beneficial.
For example, I know that $\binom{n}{k}$ can be interpreted as choosing a $k$-elemental subset of a $n$-elemental set.
Terms of the form $\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{i}$ can be interpreted as having a set $S$ with $|S|=n$. Choosing a subset $S_1 \subseteq S$ with $k$ elements, and then choosing a subset $S_2 \subseteq S_1$ with $i$ elements.
Regarding sums,I often think of them as counting cardinality of sets. But this often depends on context.
Question:
For that reason I would like to know more about (formal) interpretations of combinatorial terms and symbols.
I would be happy if someone with more expirience in this could give me some better insight how to interpret those things. (Also, are there any books or literature on this topic?)

If you find the right combinatorics book for you, and attack and solve many, many problems, then the standard symbols will become second nature to you.  Analogizes to not handing a first grader a dictionary, but instead having the first grader learn to comprehend sentences of greater and greater complexity.

@user2661923 I know how important practice is. But I would still like to have some extra literature on that.

Part of the motivation of my previous comment is that I have never seen nor heard of such literature.  Further, for math topics in general, I have similarly never seen that type of learning approach.  Instead, the intuition stretching involved in learning definitions on an instinctively level has (for me anyway) always been directly associated with attacking the pertinent problems.

I have seen math books that provided a glossary of symbols, where the symbols used in the book were defined.  However, I never considered studying the symbols, for their own sake.

@user2661923 The reason behind my intention was that I found a lot of solutions posted on here that use more of a analogy to explain those identities. But I just dislike using this kind of explainations for that. So I thought maybe, if one could think of the possible meanings behind the terms, this would yield "better" solutions. (Better as in more formal.) Especially because somethimes I have no idea how to interpret a symbol (for a combinatorial proof).

This is way too broad a question to be completely answered on this site. The answers to questions like this will come, in time, as you study and practice combinatorics.

Richard P Stanley has a lot of literature on bijective / combinatorial proofs, in particular see chapter 1 of his textbook on "Enumerative Combinatorics". In terms of practice problems he has collected a big list here. Hope this helps! :-)

@NTc5: You may find this answer about the twelvefold path helpful.

This is the way:
(although there is a shorter version at the undergraduate level)

Let me know if that is what you were asking about, since your question is broad.
I can also recommend Mazur's Guided Tour if you are graduate, or point you to Generatingfunctionology for another counting tool.
